# passing the session variable

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have 3 files in my program, I am working on a quiz system.

**quiz.php** (first file)

In this file, I am fetching the categories from database

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="" name="cat">
  <label for="sel1">Select category</label>
 <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    echo" <option  value='".$row['cat_id']."'>".$row['cat_name']."</option>";
 }?>
  </select><br>
  <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:-70px" >Start Quiz</button></center>
</div>
</form>
```

**ques_show.php** (second file)
this file displays the questions from database, based on category chosen.
I am saving the category in session variable

```
$cat=$_POST['cat']; // to get the category
$_SESSION['cat']=$cat; // saving category
//..... code
```

**answer.php** (3rd file)
This file displays the result

```
 $cat_id=$_SESSION['cat']; // error here it says undefined
$response="SELECT * FROM questions WHERE cat_id='$cat_id'";
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,$response);


        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
             if($row['ans']==$_POST[$row['q_id']]){
            $right_answer++;
        } else if($_POST[$row['q_id']]=="no_attempt"){
            $unanswered++;
        } else {
            $wrong_answer++;
        }

    }
```

session variable `$cat_id` is used to check the saved answer from database where `cat = $cat_id`

everything is working but error says in **answer.php file undefined cat**

What I am doing wrong

Comment: Also, I don't see `session_start()` anywhere.

Comment: this question is so clear, I can read right though a glass made of mud

Comment: check for errors.

Comment: you should also get into the habit of accepting answers. So far, all of the ones that have been given answers, have yet to know if they've solved them or not. Is *"Keep 'em guessing"* part of your motto? Just like this question.

Comment: session_start()  is there in my files, I have not mention above, the problem is only in passing the session variable

Comment: and we wish you all well with that. See the guy who gave you an answer below.

Comment: i have full code with database, my code is too long to paste it here, let me know if i can send zip files

Comment: Got the solution.. Thanks for your help too Sir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Things that might be wrong is, check if you initial session on page top. Other thing check if form post is working

Comment: Thank @waleed Ahmed for the help. session_start was missing on the top of the page..Thanks alot

Comment: Mark accept if it helped you

Comment: @WaleedAhmed: WTF, you stated _session_start() is there in my files, I have not mention above, the problem is only in passing the session variable_ in the comments!